# Ocaml parse read stdin filedescriptor

Tags: unix, ocaml, stdin, file-descriptor

I'm trying to parse a read from the stdin filescriptor with the following code:

```
let run () =
  let b = Bytes.create 1024 in
  let stdin_fd = Lwt_unix.stdin in
  let stdout_fd = Lwt_unix.stdout in
  (Lwt_unix.read stdin_fd b 0 1024) >>=
     (fun _  ->
        print_endline "done";
        print_endline b;
        print_endline "ok?";
        Lwt.return ())
```

When I type some text in a terminal and hit enter, it prints the text I entered. The problem is I want to get more information about the keys I entered. Let's say I did: `ctrl + v` or something, how do I get that information out of `Lwt_unix.read` ? Currently I only get the characters I typed in, how do I know if for example the `ctrl`-key ( or shift or esc) was pressed?

Comment: I think you should look at lambda-term package for getting this kind of UI information (lamba-term is used by utop) - see https://github.com/diml/lambda-term/blob/master/src/lTerm_key.mli.... but I am not so keen with this package.

Comment: This should be an answer. AFAIK you don't get modifier key information through stdin.